# Call web application on Windows Server running inside VM from Host

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vpn

I have been given a laptop. Inside this laptop I have a VirtualBox VM running Windows Server 2008. On this Virtual Server I have several sites and databases set up. I created this image to make the problem easier to visualize:

[image: software setup]

In order for the website inside the guest (in pink) to function, it needs to have access to the another network (dev). I have attempted to solve this with VPN on the Host (in blue).

Now all is working fine, except that I can't call the website inside the Guest from the Host. I should be able to navigate to:

> http://devservervm.development.site.com

And access the website, but it isn't working, I get a blank page. My Network settings for the VM are as follows:

[image]

However when I open that URL inside the VM the site opens fine with no problems.

Why is this happening? I would greatly appreciate a fix to this problem.

Comment: "I work for a large enterprise" Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: Hmm I didn't this was specific to an enterprise, I thought it would be a generic problem faced by companies all over.

Comment: enterprise == corporate == company -> off topic